# Want to create one RabbitMQ Connection object in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I am new to erlang and working on a major project based on erlang.

My use case is to push a acknowledge message, published message and delivered message from MQTT broker to Rabbitmq server.

I have defined three functions in my erlang file and each function wants to create a connection with Rabbitmq server. Each function able to create a connection with Rabbitmq with less number of hits but when large numbers of hits come to these three function then Rabbitmq stop responding due to large numbers of connections made to Rabbitmq. In a response I get an error of timed out.

What I want is want to create a global connection of Rabbitmq and same connection object is used in all the three functions.

Three functions are shown below:-

```
on_message_publish(Message, _Env) ->
%%  Getting a Raw Message
  io:format("PUBLISHING"),

  Val=element(12,Message),
%%  Making a Connection with RabbitMQ
  {ok, Connection} = amqp_connection:start(#'amqp_params_network'{}),
%%  Creating Channel
  {ok, Channel} = amqp_connection:open_channel(Connection),
%%  Declaring Queue
  % Declare = #'queue.declare'{queue = <<"erlang_message">>,durable = true},
  % #'queue.declare_ok'{queue = Queue} = amqp_channel:call(Channel, Declare),
%%  Creating Payload Message
  Payload = list_to_binary(["published|$&|",Val]),
%%  Published a Message
  Publish = #'basic.publish'{exchange = <<"celery">>},
  amqp_channel:cast(Channel, Publish, #amqp_msg{payload = Payload}),
%%  Closing Channel
  amqp_channel:close(Channel),
%%  Closing Connection
  amqp_connection:close(Connection),
  {ok, Message}.

on_message_delivered(ClientId, Message, _Env) ->
  Val=element(12,Message),
%%  Making a Connection with RabbitMQ
  {ok, Connection} = amqp_connection:start(#'amqp_params_network'{}),
%%  Creating Channel
  {ok, Channel} = amqp_connection:open_channel(Connection),
%%  Declaring Queue
  % Declare = #'queue.declare'{queue = <<"erlang_message">>,durable = true},
  % #'queue.declare_ok'{queue = Queue} = amqp_channel:call(Channel, Declare),
%%  Creating Payload Message
  Payload = list_to_binary(["published|$&|",Val]),
%%  Published a Message
  Publish = #'basic.publish'{exchange = <<"celery">>},
  amqp_channel:cast(Channel, Publish, #amqp_msg{payload = Payload}),
%%  Closing Channel
  amqp_channel:close(Channel),
%%  Closing Connection
  amqp_connection:close(Connection),
  {ok, Message}.

on_message_acked(ClientId, Message, _Env) ->
  %%  Getting a Raw Message
  Val=element(12,Message),
%%  Making a Connection with RabbitMQ
  {ok, Connection} = amqp_connection:start(#'amqp_params_network'{}),
%%  Creating Channel
  {ok, Channel} = amqp_connection:open_channel(Connection),
%%  Declaring Queue
  % Declare = #'queue.declare'{queue = <<"erlang_message">>,durable = true},
  % #'queue.declare_ok'{queue = Queue} = amqp_channel:call(Channel, Declare),
%%  Creating Payload Message
  Payload = list_to_binary(["published|$&|",Val]),
%%  Published a Message
  Publish = #'basic.publish'{exchange = <<"celery">>},
  amqp_channel:cast(Channel, Publish, #amqp_msg{payload = Payload}),
%%  Closing Channel
  amqp_channel:close(Channel),
%%  Closing Connection
  amqp_connection:close(Connection),
  {ok, Message}.
```

Comment: And how that object would prevent the Rabbit node from being overloaded?

Comment: @Amiramix  It will have only one connection rather than multiple connections of three functions. Suppose  I got 100 hits then it will make 300 asynchronous connections with Rabbitmq.

Comment: If you want to serialize access just use http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/gen_server_concepts.html You can establish one connection when initializing `gen_server` and then receive all connection requests through `handle_call` or `handle_info`. You can then serialize the connections or keep a specific amount connections open. This is an example of a `gen_server` that maintains a pool 10 processes to download files in parallel, but there are plenty of other examples on the internet: https://github.com/amiramix/humbundee/blob/master/lib/humbundee/src/hbd_pool.erl#L62